# How to use html code to design front end in react native?

Tags: html, react-native

Our design team has shared some `HTML` code with us, based on which I have to build the UI in `React Native`.

There are some tags like:

```html
    <link rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" href="vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
```

If I want to adapt these to `React Native`, how should it be? Or should I develop a `React Native` app separately without taking any reference from the `HTML`?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `react-native-css-transformer` module

1. install : `yarn add --dev react-native-css-transformer`

> For React Native v0.57 or newer / Expo SDK v31.0.0 or newer

2. Add this to `metro.config.js` in your project's root (create the
   file if it does not exist already):

```js
const { getDefaultConfig } = require("metro-config");

module.exports = (async () => {
  const {
    resolver: { sourceExts }
  } = await getDefaultConfig();
  return {
    transformer: {
      babelTransformerPath: require.resolve("react-native-css-transformer")
    },
    resolver: {
      sourceExts: [...sourceExts, "css"]
    }
  };
})();
```

**Example**

> App.css

```js
.myClass {
  color: blue;
}
.myOtherClass {
  color: red;
}
.my-dashed-class {
  color: green;
}
```

> Usage

```js
import styles from "./App.css";
<MyElement style={styles.myClass} />

<MyElement style={styles["my-dashed-class"]} />
```

**Documention** :
[react-native-css-transformer](https://github.com/kristerkari/react-native-css-transformer)

Answer (score 1):

You can't use HTML tags directly in react native projects,

So you have got two options -

1. Re write code with React Native elements such View etc..
2. Import those parts as individual stand by own webviews, https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-webview/blob/master/README.md